# How to make a PDF inside object tag responsive?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my website responsive, and I have a PDF viewer in object tags in the body simply like this:

```
<object width="950" height="800" data="images/ah.pdf"></object>
```

Since the width and height are defined, I changed it to:

```
<div id="custom">
<object data="images/ah.pdf"></object>
</div>
```

and then adjusted the div in the css portion using percentages. My problem is that the whole PDF viewer does not show, and instead is a small box that has scroll bars on the sides, so you have to scroll left right and top bottom. Is there any way I can get it to adjust the PDF size according to the window size instead of just adjusting the PDF viewer alone? I hope this makes sense as clear as possible. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Change your object tag to this:

```
<object data="images/ah.pdf" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block;"></object>
```

You can add the style to a class, then include the class in your object tag. Or use another variation to get the styles applied. The width and height will be the same size as its parent container.

Answer (score 4):

@Adam answer may work. I honestly don't deal with  much/ BUt I will tell you that I have setup iframes for displays and they are responsive-compatible

This is what I'd do

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="embed-container">
        <iframe src="/images/myPDF.pdf" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>

.content {
   width: 50%;
   margin: 0px auto;
}

.embed-container {
   height: 0;
   width: 100%;
   padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* play with this until right */
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
}

.embed-container iframe {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}
```